# Removing HTML inline style from jquery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently using bootstrap for the css framework and have successfully placed the video on the DOM. My only issue is the video is pushing my container down when I want it placed over the video. I Noticed in the HTML that #big-video-vid contains inline styles, and one of them being height

```
<div id="big-video-vid" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-controls-disabled vjs-has-started vjs-user-inactive vjs-playing" style="width: 1496.1246105919004px; height: 938px; display: block; top: 0px; left: -237.06230529595018px;">
```

When I remove the height from the inline, everything works like how I want it. I tried using jquery to remove the inline style eg.: `$('#big-video-vid').css('height', '');`  but no avail. Any tips?

Here is the library i'm using https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js

Comment: Try `$("#big-video-vid").css("height", "auto");`

Comment: Are you running `$('#big-video-vid').css('height', '');` after `#big-video-vid` and its styles are added to the dom? The snippet you wrote will definitely remove the height attribute completely.

Comment: Duplicate the error in a jsFiddle please.

Comment: This probably isn't the fix you want. For example, when the browser window is resized the `height` will be added back by BigVideo.js. [You're asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Archer still not removing it.

Comment: Worth a try.  When trying to remove an inline style value, it's best to go to the default value, rather than set it to nothing.  At least it's ruled out.

Comment: @thirtydot so what should I do?

Comment: Provide a demo of your problem. Upload your test page somewhere, or make a http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/ demo. The author of BigVideo.js probably didn't add the `height` attribute for fun, there's some reason it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
#big-video-vid {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#big-video-vid").css({'height' : 'auto'});
```